# communication between Android devices from different computer

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is it possible t make two android emulator on eclipse communicate from two differents machines which are connected with a fast ethernet link ?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The outgoing side just works, but the incoming side (whichever one is receiving the connection) is a bit more complicated.  You would set up an emulator or adb port forward, but that only makes a port on the loopback interface ("localhost" ie 127.0.0.1) of the machine hosting that emulator ring through to the the emulator android device it is hosting.  It probably will not accept connections on the external network.  So to get around that, you can ssh from one hosting machine into the other, and set up an ssh port forward so a port on the loopback of the connecting machine forwards to a port on the loopback of the receiving machine and then forwards into its emulator...

Answer (score 1):

First, android emulators are independent of Eclipse. That is, you don't need Eclipse to run the emulators:

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator.exe -avd <AVD name>
```

So the answer to your question applies to both scenarios: emulator running from Eclipse or running without Eclipse at all.

As for your question: Yes, it is possible. The android emulator is a basically a heavily customized linux box.

From the command line, type: `adb shell` and you will find yourself in a familiar linux shell. :)

Then ping the IP address of the other emulator and see how communication flows.