# Get more computation power for developing java application

Tags: android, eclipse, distributed

I'm developing Java application using Eclipse IDE. problem is my PC is every low performance with XP. My company has many PCs free. So is there way to distribute free computer power and get that computer power for my Android application development?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This is an interesting question. And there are distributed IDE, for example Xcode's grid compiler so it is not an unknown problem, either.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect because (a) it's not programming-related, and (b) it's unlikely the issue is anything other than emulator speed, which I believe would be difficult to distribute.

Comment: Maybe you could run android emulator on different machine?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864291/communication-between-android-devices-from-different-computer

Comment: Your question is almost about "slow emulator", isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your whole computer is slow and the UI is generally unresponsive, then no there is nothing you can do. If you are writing an Android application that has trouble running on a desktop, than you have a problem in your code/design that you aren't going to solve with more developer hardware.

Technically, you may be able to distribute an android emulator through [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), but unless you're working for free, the time-cost would be greater than that of a new computer. If your employer values your time, they will buy you a decent computer.